# Can Swift 1 code run on iOS 9?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I was wondering if anyone knows whether or not Swift (version 1) Code will be able to be run on iOS 9, or if the syntax will need to be updated to allow it. I'm assuming you probably don't *have* to update the code, but if anyone has any opinions please do share!

Comment: the code doesn't run on it — the compiled app does.

Comment: the ios9 may handle the app as vikingsegundo said. just xcode7 that will probably ask to migrate to swift 2.0 as JAL pointed out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Xcode 7 will ship with a Swift Migrator tool (similar to the [Swift 1.1 to 1.2 migrator](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=22) used in Xcode 6), which will help developers migrate Swift 1.2 projects to work with Swift 2.

Projects written with Swift 1.x in Xcode versions previous to 7 will run on iOS 9.  Any projects written with Xcode 7 must use Swift 2.

For more information, check out the [Swift Resources](https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/) page on Apple's Developer Portal

Comment: Xcode 7 does ship with a migrator, but this doesn't really answer OP's question or whether Swift 1.x code *will run* on iOS 9.

Comment: do you have any reference for your claim *"Swift 1.x code will not work with iOS 9 and Xcode 7."*

Comment: *"Any projects written with Xcode 7 must use Swift 2."* can you back up this?

Comment: @vikingosegundo See the download page on Apple's Developer portal: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/.  Xcode 7 ships with the Swift 2 compiler.

Comment: and what makes you believe that this compiler can't handle Swift 1.x? maybe you are correct, but it should be more that a headline on a marketing page to back it up.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Xcode 7 ships with the Swift 2 compiler ONLY.  Whenever the Swift language is updated, previous versions of the compiler/language are no longer supported, just like with Xcode 6.

Comment: Update: I am loading my phone with iOS 9 right now, will test an app written in swift 1 and answer my question!

Comment: I just did the same in the Simulator: could not compile Swift 1.2 code with Xcode 7. The conversion tool did a amazing job: 50 errors after running it.

Comment: Does Swift 1.x runs on iOS 10, 100% compatible?

Comment: @ArildoJunior Yes, but you can't write a new Swift 1.x app and target the iOS 10 SDK.